# limit of a sequence of integral functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, normed-spaces, uniform-convergence

I have to study punctual and uniform convergence of the following succession
$$f_n(x)=n\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}\dfrac{1}{e^{t^2}}dt.$$
I showed that the functions $f_n$ are uniformly convergent in $\mathbb R$ but I'm not able to calculate explicitly the limit function $f(x):=\underset{n\to +\infty}{\lim}f_n(x)$.
My idea was to split the integral in half and use the characteristic function of the domain of integration but this seems to be inconclusive.

Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: It seems that the integral converges to zero since the interval gets smaller and smaller, and the integrand is a very nice function (bounded).

Comment: by the FTC, $f_n(x) = \Phi(x+n^{-1}) - \Phi(x - n^{-1})$, where $\Phi$ is a continuous function. You can then interchange $\Phi$ and $\lim$ to obtain $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: This was the solution I got studying it like the integral between $0$ and $x+1/n$ minus the integral between $0$ and $x-1/n$, but the solution should be $2e^{-x^2}$... how??

Comment: $2e^{-x^2}$ is the limit of $\color{red}{n}f_n(x)$. Must be a typo.

Comment: @metamorphy I forgot the $n$ term but I should have noticed it earlier... I think it is too late now  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the updated question, the pointwise limit is $2e^{-x^2}$. Its easy to see that we just need to check
$$ 2n\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}|e^{-t^2} - e^{-x^2}| dt \to 0$$
Since $e^{-t^2}$ is continuous at $t=x$, for each $\epsilon$ there is $\delta$ such that for all $|t-x| < \delta$,
$$  |e^{-t^2} - e^{-x^2}|\le \epsilon$$
Hence for all $n$ such that $1/n<\delta$,
$$2n\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}|e^{-t^2} - e^{-x^2}| dt\le \epsilon $$
this shows exactly what we need. This basically proves a special case of the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem
$$ f\in L^1_{loc}\implies f(x) = \lim_{r\to 0} \frac1{|B_r(x)|}\int_{B_r(x)} f(y)dy \quad \text{a.e.}$$
which is not trivial to prove in full generality, but much easier when $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for the answer But I'm not understanding if you started the proof already knowing the limit function. Because I think your answer proves clearly that the limit function is $2e^{-x^2}$ but what should I do if I want to find it by calculations (I mean studying tle limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n$)?

Comment: @Alchemist I started the proof knowing that you are computing an average of a continuous function $f(t)$ near $t=x$, so the value is $\approx f(x)$. This intuition is made precise by e.g. the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem I mentioned at the bottom. It falls into the same category as "I can draw the graph, now lets make this rigorous..."

Answer (score 1):

$$f_n(x)=\int_{x-\frac{1}{n}}^{x+\frac{1}{n}}\dfrac{1}{e^{t^2}}dt=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi }
   \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{n}-x\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1}{n}+x\right)\right)$$ Using the infinite series representation of $\text{erf}(t)$ and continuing with Taylor series, when $n$ is large
$$f_n(x)\sim g_n(x)=\frac{2 e^{-x^2}}{n}\Bigg[1+\frac{2 x^2-1}{3 n^2}+\frac{4 x^4-12 x^2+3}{30
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^6}\right) \Bigg]$$

For example, using $x=\pi$ and $n=2^k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \frac {f_n(x)} {g_n(x)} \\
 0 & 1.28419669254952350166175610011 \\
 1 & 1.02205560798133497330954918511 \\
 2 & 1.00074377793925422180746341333 \\
 3 & 1.00001499797854822520136495734 \\
 4 & 1.00000025126261683720744981856 \\
 5 & 1.00000000399669102804908420208 \\
 6 & 1.00000000006272933330307433397 \\
 7 & 1.00000000000098124840982741539 \\
 8 & 1.00000000000001533631803233576 \\
 9 & 1.00000000000000023964681613758 \\
 10 & 1.00000000000000000374454731476 \\
 11 & 1.00000000000000000005850880888 \\
 12 & 1.00000000000000000000091420114 \\
 13 & 1.00000000000000000000001428440 \\
 14 & 1.00000000000000000000000022319 \\
 15 & 1.00000000000000000000000000349 \\
 16 & 1.00000000000000000000000000005 \\
 17 & 1.00000000000000000000000000000 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Is there another way to see this? Anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Do any of these alternate forms based upon Claude's formula help? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B2+e%5E%7B-x%5E2%7D%7D%7Bn%7D%5CBigg%5B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B2+x%5E2-1%7D%7B3+n%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B4+x%5E4-12+x%5E2%2B3%7D%7B30++++n%5E4%7D%2BO%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%5E6%7D%5Cright%29+%5CBigg%5D

Comment: I don't think we have to do the exercise with this method because we've never seen Claude's formula or something similar. I think there is a longer and tedious way to solve the problem which is the method I shoul apply.

Comment: I quite like the cascading zeroes :)

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le f_n(x)=\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}e^{-t^2}dt\le\int_{x-1/n}^{x+1/n}dt=\left(x+\frac 1n\right) - \left(x-\frac 1n\right)=\frac2n.
$$
So $f_n(x)$ congerves uniformly to the null function over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you but I've already reached this result. I had problems in calculating the explicit formula of the limit function $f(x):=\lim_{n\to+\infty}f_n(x)$

Comment: This result gurantees that $f(x)=0$ and thsat the limit is uniform. Both in one line.

Comment: The limit function in the solution is not zero but $f(x)=2\exp (-x^2)$... Maybe there is a mistake...

Comment: No, it isn't. The limit function is $f(x)=0$.